# Video Conferencing Integration Quickblox

Tags: android, dependencies, quickblox

I am trying to do video conferencing in android app the best solution i got is to use quickblox api but i have some troubles in building its dependencies can anybody help me with this it will be a great favour.

Comment: check out my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47117314/2437655 for quickblox integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the examples of official github profile of quickblox; after download the examples of correct version (I'm using now the 3.0 version of Quickblox SDK for android) you should see the `.gradle` files of `sample-videochat-webrtc` folder and copy some lines in your correct `.gradle` file and run gradle again.

If you don't read all examples, the short way to add video chat dependencies to your app is adding these lines to `app/build.gradle file:`

```
//First add QuickBlox's repository
//after 'android' section and before of 'dependencies' section
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
    }
}

dependencies{
    //... dependencies

    //The QB dependencies
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.0'
    compile ('com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.0') { transitive = true }
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.0'

    //... more dependencies
}
```